# Cut a polygon with two lines in Shapely

Tags: python, shapely

I am trying to cut a `shapely.geometry.Polygon` instance in two parts with two lines. For example, in the code below, `polygon` is a ring and if we cut it with `line1` and `line2` we should get two partial rings, one w/ 270 degrees and one with 90 degrees. Would there be a clean way to do this?

```
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString, Polygon

polygon = Point(0, 0).buffer(2).difference(Point(0, 0).buffer(1))
line1 = LineString([(0, 0), (3, 3)])
line2 = LineString([(0, 0), (3, -3)])
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a function to split one geometry by another in Shapely as of version 1.6.0 (Aug 2017), so there is no need to roll your own anymore. See the docs for: [`shapely.ops.split(geom, splitter)`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#shapely.ops.split)

Note that the older answers on this thread were written *before* the splitting function was in Shapely - they are now effectively obsolete.

Answer (score 7):

Ken Watford answered [here](http://community-gispython-org-community-projects.955323.n3.nabble.com/Community-Shapely-how-to-split-a-polygon-with-a-line-td1915160.html) about using `buffer` and `difference` to do the trick, w/ the drawback of losing a bit of the area. An example code below:

```
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString, Polygon

polygon = Point(0, 0).buffer(2).difference(Point(0, 0).buffer(1))
line1 = LineString([(0, 0), (3, 3)])
line2 = LineString([(0, 0), (3, -3)])

line1_pol = line1.buffer(1e-3)
line2_pol = line2.buffer(1e-3)

new_polygon = polygon.difference(line1_pol).difference(line2_pol)
```

Works for now, and I'd be interested to see whether there is another (potentially w/o losing area) method!

Comment: I think any exact solution would require to implement the math problem behind from scratch, with significant lines of code. Specially in the general terms you are setting the problem.

Answer (score 5):

```
from shapely.ops import linemerge, unary_union, polygonize
from shapely.geometry import LineString, Polygon

# Define the Polygon and the cutting line
line = LineString([(-5, -5), (5, 5)])
polygon = Polygon([(-1, -1), (1, -1), (1, 1), (-1, 1)])


def cut_polygon_by_line(polygon, line):
    merged = linemerge([polygon.boundary, line])
    borders = unary_union(merged)
    polygons = polygonize(borders)
    return list(polygons)

def plot(shapely_objects, figure_path='fig.png'):
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
    import geopandas as gpd
    boundary = gpd.GeoSeries(shapely_objects)
    boundary.plot(color=['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'yellow'])
    plt.savefig(figure_path)

result = cut_polygon_by_line(polygon, line)
print(result)
plot(result)
print(result[0].intersection(result[1]))
```

The result is

```
[<shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x7f50dcf46d68>, 
 <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x7f50dcf46da0>]
LINESTRING (-1 -1, 1 1)
```

[image]

Comment: In case you have two lines, you can just add the second line in the `linemerge()` like this: `merged = linemerge([polygon.boundary, line1, line2])`