# How to convert polygon that touches itself in a line into valid polygon?

Tags: python, polygon, shapely

I'm using shapely and python to divide polygons into smaller pieces: trapezoids, parallelograms with sides parallel to x-axis and triangles with side parallel to x-axis. Initial data come from .gds file and is presented like list of tuples x,y coords. For my purpose I used difference method like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39340336/7511266). But I get stack when polygon has [holes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fq8Ro.png), for example:

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
points = [(0.0, -1.0), (0.0, 2.0), (3.0, 2.0), (3.0, 1.0), (1.0, 1.0), (1.0, 0.0), (2.0, 0.0), (2.0, 1.0), (3.0, 1.0), (3.0,-1.0)]
poly = Polygon(points)
print(poly.is_valid)
#Self-intersection at or near point 2 1
#False
```

So the question is what is the simpliest way how to convert this list of points into hull and holes for correct creation of polygon?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard trick for this is to use `poly.buffer(0)` (see [the shapely manual](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#object.buffer)).

```
polyb = poly.buffer(0)
print(shapely.geometry.mapping(polyb))
# {'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': (((0.0, -1.0), (0.0, 2.0), (3.0, 2.0), (3.0, 1.0), (3.0, -1.0), (0.0, -1.0)), ((2.0, 1.0), (1.0, 1.0), (1.0, 0.0), (2.0, 0.0), (2.0, 1.0)))}
print(polyb.is_valid)
# True
```

Comment: Thanks for fast reply! I had read that before I wrote here, but I was confused with my usual way checking of polygon `x,y = shape.exterior.coords.xy` and of course there were no interior points. So you cleared my mind. Thanks!